# Vuex Store not updating when changing table values

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuex, quasar-framework

I am working on a table using Quasar framework's Q-Popup-edit and Vuex Store.

It populates correctly.  However, when I change values on the table, it goes back to its current value and is not reflected at all.

Here is my table:

```
tableData: [
        {
          'FrozenYogurt' : {
            'topping': 'strawberry'
          },
          'FrozenYogurtPart2' : {
            'topping2': 'strawberry2'
          }
        },
        {
          'IceCreamSandwich' : {
            'baseFlavor': 'chocolate',
            'somethingAgain': 'chocolatiest'
          }
        },
        {
          'CreamPuff' : {
            'sourceBakery': 'Starbucks'
         }
        }
      ]
```

My Vuex mutation:

```
  mutations: {
    saveUpdatedData (newVal) {
      console.log('inside MUTATION saveUpdatedData')
      state.tableData.length = 0
      state.tableData.push(newVal)
    }
  }
```

And using a two-way computed property (get/set) to populate the table:

```
    tableRows: {
      get: function () {
        console.log('inside GET')    
        return this.$store.state.tableData.reduce((acc, item) => {
          Object.keys(item).forEach(name => {
            Object.keys(item[name]).forEach(property => {
              acc.push({ name, property, value: item[name][property]})
            })
          })
          return acc
        }, [])
      },
      set: function (newValue) {
        console.log('inside SET')
        this.$store.commit('saveUpdatedData', newValue)
      }
    }
```

But the `set()` function isn't being called at all.

And finally my Vue code:

```
     <q-table
        :data="tableRows"
        :columns="columns"
        :rows-per-page-options="[]"
        row-key="name" wrap-cells>

        <template v-slot:body="props">
          <q-tr :props="props">
            <q-td key="desc" :props="props">
              {{ props.row.name }}
              <q-popup-edit v-model="props.row.name" buttons>
                <q-input v-model="props.row.name" dense autofocus counter ></q-input>
              </q-popup-edit>
            </q-td>

            <q-td key="property" :props="props">
              {{ props.row.property }}
              <q-popup-edit buttons v-model="props.row.property">
                <q-input type="textarea" v-model="props.row.property" autofocus counter @keyup.enter.stop></q-input>
              </q-popup-edit>
            </q-td>

            <q-td key="value" :props="props">
              {{ props.row.value }}
              <q-popup-edit v-model="props.row.value" buttons>
                <q-input v-model="props.row.value" dense autofocus ></q-input>
              </q-popup-edit>
            </q-td>

          </q-tr>
        </template>
      </q-table>
```

How can I make the changes reflect on the vuex store??

CodePen here:
https://codepen.io/kzaiwo/pen/BaNYbZZ?editors=1011

Help!

Answer (score 1):

You can extend your computed property by using computed getter and setter:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter

Your existing computation code moves to the get function.
The set function needs to be implemented.

Comment: I tried to implement the get/set functions of my computed property and it still does not seem to work. In fact, ```set``` function is never called. Added console.log and it does not print at all.  What am I possibly doing wrong?  CodePen updated: https://codepen.io/kzaiwo/pen/BaNYbZZ?editors=1011

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this url https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html
You will find the correct way to mutate the vuex store.

Comment: I have updated my codepen with proper mutations and a two-way (get/set) computed property.. Still not updating :( Help!

Comment: wait I am checking

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that you still have to use data prop like in the docs. (I have tried computed property setter but it wouldn't work)

To integrate it with the store you can use the following solution: https://codepen.io/woothu/pen/VwLXzNQ?editors=1011

```
  data () {
    return {
columns: [
  { name: 'desc', align: 'left', label: 'Data Element', field: 'desc', sortable: true, style: 'min-width: 180px; max-width: 180px;' },
  { name: 'property', align: 'center', label: 'Property', field: 'property', sortable: true, style: 'min-width: 20px; max-width: 20px;' },
  { name: 'value', align: 'left', label: 'Value', field: 'value', sortable: true, style: 'min-width: 300px; max-width: 300px; word-wrap: break-word; font-family: Consolas; font-size: 13px' }
],
   tableRows: null
    }
  },
  beforeMount () {
    this.tableRows = this.$store.state.tableData.reduce((acc, item) => {
      Object.keys(item).forEach(name => {
        Object.keys(item[name]).forEach(property => {
          acc.push({ name, property, value: item[name][property]})
        })
      })
      return acc
    }, [])
  },
  watch: {
     tableRows: {
       deep: true,
       handler (val) {      
         this.$store.commit('saveUpdatedData', val)
       }
     }
  }
```

Btw. I think the QTable component should emit the event when it changes data with the updated data structure. (Or make some other functionality to enable handling Vuex) It is probably worth opening the PR with mention of this discussion.